# UIViewController memory leak

Tags: swift, uitableview, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

My ViewController isn't being deallocated. Using the Memory Debugger, I found that the UITableView is holding onto it. I've created this TableView as an IBOutlet to the storyboard. This is the graph I'm getting from the Memory Debugger. Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Thank you

[image: Memory Leaks Graph]

Answer (score 0):

You're storing a pointer to the `UIViewController` in a `NSDictionary`? If so, that's probably the problem (although it's hard to say without seeing some code). `NSDictionary` will strongly retain an object added to it. Instead you can use `NSMapTable` with a `strongToWeakObjects` construction which will weakly retain your `UIViewController` and solve your leak.

Comment: nope i'm not storing it in any NSDictionary thats why it seems so weird

Comment: Without ViewController's code it is not possible to tell who retain controller. First of all check if some control holds strong reference to controller, some delegate or so.